# Java Idiom or Library for Return Value and Return Value Validity?

Tags: java, return, return-value, dto

**The Problem**

I have Data Transfer Objects with many accessors that return values of different types, for example `Integer`, `Double`, `String`, etc.

The objects are initialized from parsing text, where a field that is an `Integer` in the text being parsed, may also have a value of "INVALID."  The user (developer in another module) of the class should know if the value they are getting is valid or not without having to catch an exception.

**What I'm Considering**

```
public class FooDto
{
    private Integer a;
    private Double b;
    private Long c;

    public FooDto(String rawText)
    {
        // Initialize members from rawText...
    }

    public Integer getA()
    {
        return a;
    }

    boolean isAValid()
    {
        boolean isValid = // determine validity
        return isValid; 
    }

    public Double getB()
    {
        return b;
    }

    public boolean isBValid()
    {
        boolean isValid = // determine validity
        return isValid;
    }
}
```

**The Question**

Is there a best practice, or library out there with `IntegerWithValidityCheck`, `DoubleWithValidityCheck`, etc. that I should be using? To be clear, this is different than just returning null.  The return value could be null -- if the value doesn't exist in the text file, a valid value, or the specific case of "INVALID."

Comment: "The user of the class should know if the value they are getting is valid or not without having to catch an exception" <-- what is the user here? The POJO user? The end user? If no exception, how do you plan to tell the user that the value was erroneous?

Comment: The POJO user. The case where a value is "INVALID" is expected, possible behavior as opposed to just being null or something.  How I tell the user that the value was erroneous is the point of the question.  I'm considering having a validity check for each value returned as you can see in the example.

Comment: OK, then how are these POJOs created in the first place? You say this is a DTO, therefore the values are already in there, even invalid? What about returning a builder for this DTO instead with an `.isValid()` method, and the user would then check before `.build()` (decorated maybe with a `.getErrors()` method)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, you have two options:

1. The easiest is just to throw an exception for the exceptional case. I would imagine the case where the value isn't present would suit?
2. Create a new generic class that you return from each method. It can have an `isInvalid()` method, which indicates whether the value was marked as "INVALID". If the user still calls `getValue()` despite being told it was invalid, throw an exception.